# screen scrape Salesforce with REST GET call from Apex

Tags: apex, rest-api

Consider this code snippet from [my answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/4688/799) to rao's question:

```
String requestUrl = '/services/data/v26.0/sobjects/User/describe';
Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + requestUrl);
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());

HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
String output = res.getBody();
System.debug(output);
```

Works like a charm (provided you've added the instance to "Remote Site Settings" of course).

Now try with standard Salesforce page, for example

```
String requestUrl = '/001/o'; // or '/home/home.jsp' or anything else
```

And you get back this weird "placeholder" regardless which page you'll call.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<script>
var escapedHash = '';
var url = 'https://test.salesforce.com/?ec=302&startURL=%2F001%2Fo';
if (window.location.hash) {
   escapedHash = '%23' + window.location.hash.slice(1);
}
if (window.location.replace){ 
window.location.replace(url + escapedHash);
} else {;
window.location.href = url + escapedHash;
} 
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Any idea what to do to get to the actual page?

Pass some undocumented header? Go through the frontdoor.jsp like [suggested on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7842311/313628)? Or maybe I should expose `PageReference.getContent()` as a REST service :D

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Please don't screen-scrape - it's just about the most fragile integration you can imagine. With the release of the [Analytics API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_analytics/index.htm), it's also now largely unnecessary**

Having said that, the `Authorization` HTTP header only works with API requests. For web pages like `/001/o` or `/home/home.jsp` you need to set the `sid` cookie instead. For example,

```
String requestUrl = '/001/o';
Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + requestUrl);
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setHeader('Cookie','sid='+UserInfo.getSessionId()); 

HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
String output = res.getBody();
System.debug(output);
```

Yields

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html class="ext-strict"><head><script type="text/javascript" src="/jslibrary/1351189248000/sfdc/JiffyStubs.js"></script>
<title>Accounts: Home ~ salesforce.com - Developer Edition</title>
<!-- LOTS MORE VALID PAGE DATA -->
```

Comment: and of course, totally unsupported, there's an API for a reason.

Comment: Yes - I meant to say "please don't screen-scrape - it's just about the most fragile integration you can imagine". In fact, I'll go back and edit that in right now!

Comment: I know, I know, I've seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841998/treat-salesforce-visualforce-page-as-an-external-widget/ and http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/337/can-report-data-be-accessed-programatically But do you have better idea how to retrieve results of any report with apex? Ideally not only flat details but also grouped (subtotals or matrix)? Without metadata api, orgy of XML parsing and ugly dynamic SOQL generator?

Comment: @eyescream added link to Analytics API.

Answer (score 2):

Amazing help, Pat(@metadaddy)... this has allowed me to create some marvelous personal developer toys, like a recursive Show All Dependencies!

However, like Simon(@superfell) said, this is not only horribly unsupported and incredibly hard to maintain, but the implementation of this will most likely occur through heart-sinking Pattern and Matcher use, or unimaginable String search methods... since the page most likely won't successfully load into a Dom.Document out-of-the-box.

However, if you can survive without having this be a headless process (and you're really a glutton for punishment), may I suggest approaching this inside a VisualForce page using JavaScript?  DOM access will make whatever you're going to do SO much easier.... and after you conquer the hurdle of learning Salesforce page drawing patterns and naming conventions, you'll be in much better shape than from server side coding.

Comment: I needed "only" to scrape the results from running a report (I had to send csv attachment while standard "schedule report" embeds HTML and shows only first 2K rows). I agree it's ugly, unsupported etc... but if my code is in the answer http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/4688/799 JS won't help me, right? Especially that said JS would have to be cross domain, coming with its own set of headaches.