# How can we identify all the workflows in the system which have Time-Dependent workflow actions?

Tags: time-dependent-workflow

I have around 50+ workflows rules in our org. And there may be around 5 to 10 rules which Have time dependent workflow actions. How can I easily identify which workflow rule has one?

Comment: I don't know about 'easily', but as a developer I just search within the eclipse IDE for the term 'workflowTimeTriggers'.

Comment: Are you sure that this info is available in eclipse? If both tooling API & Meta data API do not provide details about Workflow Queue object then how eclipse which use these API can give information about Workflow Queue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently both tooling API & Meta data API do not provide details about Workflow Queue object where information about time dependent workflow is stored.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_types_list.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/reference_objects_list.htm

So there there is no legitimate way by which you can do this. But there is workaround that you can use.

You can set naming convention where all time dependent workflows must start with name "Time_XXXXX" using any of above api you can get the list of all workflows and search for "Time_" sting in name field.

```
/services/data/v34.0/tooling/query/?q=Select+id,+name+from+WorkflowRule
```

The other work around is screen scrape Salesforce with REST GET call from Apex which not recommended.

[screen scrape Salesforce with REST GET call from Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4692/screen-scrape-salesforce-with-rest-get-call-from-apex)

Comment: well if u r having a naming standard, then u can have a list view to filter on the WFR name starting with Time_ to easily see them

Comment: Yes, this will work if you don't need list in your code.

Comment: Thank you guys. Mine is a one off scenario, so I will manually open the workflows and see if there is one and update the name of the workflow rules for future references.