# How to get the current sandbox-name programmatically (dynamically) via APEX?

Tags: apex, administration, sandbox

Now after all mere subscribers has per default a lot of sandboxes available, I need a way to programmatically (dynamically) get the sandbox-name of the sandbox org where the actual code is executed.

Just for clarification: I'm not looking for the **name of the org**, but the **name of the sandbox**, which are two different things.

One example purpose for this requirement is to tag notification emails, so that it's clear which sandbox-org has created it. For sure I don't want to hardcode it. Also I don't want to use a custom setting.

If found a few unclean approaches like

- `UserInfo.getUserName().substringAfterLast('.');` ==> this is not reliable, username might have been changed or a system-user might act. But this comes closest to what I need.
- use of `Organization.IsSandbox` ==> not good enough, does not tell me which of the 25+ possible sandboxes it is. Only that's not production. I need more
- use of `Organization.Name` ==> all the same for all sandboxes
- use of `Organization.InstanceName` ==> provides the server name like CS83, very nice, but not good enough

I think there is no officially supported way to get it... but I'm not 100% sure...

Is there any approach to "hack" that sandbox name out of the guts of the platform? I need no sample code, just an idea or a concept is good enough for me.

Comment: `Userinfo.getOrganizationId()` might help. One time process keep this track in some sheet and next time you can easily find.

Comment: Thanks @TusharSharma , but the OrganizationId changes on every refresh, so it would be manual work plus error prone. Looking for something 100% dynamic.

Comment: Is there any particular reason not to create a custom setting and store the Sandbox's name on it? AFAIK it is not possible to obtain the name programatically the way you want. Every article I can find on the net suggests SOQL on Organization or getting the bits after '.com' on the user's name.

Comment: @Renato that would get wiped every refresh. Custom metadata *could* work...

Comment: @AdrianLarson wouldn't the metadata revert back to production values too? Either way with custom settings or metadata, after each sandbox refresh the admin needs to go one-time update the value for that sandbox.

Comment: @UweHeim, did any of the below answers help out? if so, please mark one as checked, thanks!

Answer (score 13):

After Spring'16 release there is an ability to specify an Apex class which executes every time the sandbox is copied. See [SandboxPostCopy Interface](https://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_deployment_sandbox_postcopy_script.htm). You can get the sandbox name from `SandboxContext` and store it in a custom setting. Notice the example indicates this method signature exists: `SandboxContext.sandboxName()`.

```
global class HelloWorld implements SandboxPostCopy {
    global void runApexClass(SandboxContext context) {
        System.debug('Hello Tester Pester ' + context.organizationId() + ' 
                  ' + context.sandboxId() + context.sandboxName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Pity the `SandboxContext` class is not documented... It's unclear how to pull the name from that class based purely on what you have shared here.

Comment: `SandboxPostCopy` interface is [documented](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_System_SandboxPostCopy.htm)

Comment: That is an entirely different class. @Vadim Luckily the example contains the method needed to answer this question.

Comment: You're not missing much in SandboxContext:     
`ID organizationId();`, `ID sandboxId();`, `String sandboxName();` is all you get

Answer (score 7):

There is now an official solution that is out with the [Spring' 22 release](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_apex_domain_classes.htm&type=5&release=236).
You can use the new `getSandboxName()` method:

```
System.Domain d = System.DomainParser.parse(URL.getOrgDomainUrl());
System.debug(d.getSandboxName());
```

You can get more information about this new method in the Apex Reference Guide [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_Domain.htm#apex_System_Domain_getSandboxName).
There are also so other new and useful methods like `getMyDomainName()`.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is screen scraping. Take a look at this answer on how to scrape screen using http request. [screen scrape Salesforce with REST GET call from Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4692/screen-scrape-salesforce-with-rest-get-call-from-apex)

Please note 2 things

1) This approach seems fragile
2) You can use it from JavaScript and Apex

There is idea posted for for this feature. https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Dld9AAC

So, seems like we will have to leave with workarounds mentioned in OP + the one i mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The DomainParser class is the best way to find the name of the actual sandbox you are working in. (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_apex_domain_classes.htm&release=236&type=5)

I think there may be some confusion from looking at previous answers...

context.SandboxName() will give you the Organization name as listed in the Company Information section. In my experience this mirrors prod in all sandboxes, and is certainly what I get when I try the above example.

I've tested Fabiens answer above and this will give you the name of the actual sandbox you are in as it is listed in the Sandboxes section in production. This is what I was looking for and I'd imagine its what most people are looking for when they visit this question