# Custom settings set url to match which environment I am in

Tags: apex, webservices, customsetting

I believe i want to use hierarchical custom settings so that in salesforce my lightning component makes a webservice external call based on the environment I'm in

1. sandbox (dev) calls webservice-dev url
2. sandbox (test) calls webservice-test url
3. production calls webservice-prod url

I am going to have my apex class that gets the http request make a call to my custom settings entry

What I've tried in my apex code

```
talend_esb_url__c.getInstance('dev').URL__c;
```

this doesnt work because I need my lightning component to make this decision dynamically, a hard coded dev will simply migrate up/ become issue on a prod redeploy

```
talend_esb_url__c config = talend_esb_url__c.getOrgDefaults().URL__c;
```

this doesnt work as the org defaults are always shown (not by environment)

tried selecting organization to determine if im in a sandbox, but this doesnt work as we have more than 1 sandboxes

```
select Id, IsSandbox from Organization limit 1
```

I want to create a custom setting for a webservice callout url that I can change dynamically based on which salesforce environment I am in

EDIT:

this is actually a duplicate of [How to get the current sandbox-name programmatically (dynamically) via APEX?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/128838/how-to-get-the-current-sandbox-name-programmatically-dynamically-via-apex) basically the same situation

I'd close the question if i could

Comment: Please include the code you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: url is the only option to understand

Comment: @AdrianLarson updated to hopefully make my use case / question clear