# Report CSV export from API

Tags: reporting, api

Right now we are using Beatbox for the connection between Python and Salesforce.

We were wondering if its possible to get the csv file from the report export using the following URL using Python Requests? http://python-requests.org/

https://INSTANCE.salesforce.com/REPORTID?export=1&enc=UTF-8&xf=csv

What would we need to make this happen? I'm hoping we could get something by putting the sessionI in the URL parameter or the cookie? As far as I know, Conga Composer gets the data from the reports right?

Comment: There is a very similar question: [Can report data be accessed programatically?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/337/can-report-data-be-accessed-programatically). Most of the details you need are there. You can pass the SessionId in the HTTP request cookies.