# How to send scheduled report to a contact?

Tags: reporting, scheduled-apex, case

Is there any workaround to send a "cases" `scheduled report` to case.contact?

I know that scheduled report are sent to users, but I cant find how to assign contact to report recipients.

Do I have to implement an `Apex Scheduler` class?

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy solution to do it with code. See this question for additional details on [how to access report data from code](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/337/can-report-data-be-accessed-programatically).

There is an inexpensive solution available using [Conga Courier](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016ZopEAE)