# Can we create dashboard without reports?

Tags: reporting

Can we create a dashboard (like pie chart or bar chart) without reports? i meant through visualforce code using map or list as the input for the dashboard component?

Thanks,
Baskaran

Comment: Check out:  http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14571/access-reports-though-api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. Have a look at visualforce charting, you can also use other libraries (google charts, morris.js, etc).

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_quick_start_advanced_google_charts.htm#pages_quick_start_advanced_google_charts

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_charting.htm

Answer (score 2):

Here's the Analytics API docs.  I think this is what you're looking for::

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_analytics/salesforce_analytics_rest_api.pdf