# How to add data from list to excel using apex coding

Tags: apex, email

I am querying some fields of Account objects records. And i am storing them in a list. Now i want to send this data through mail with  excel sheet attached(which contains list data of Account Records) on click of send email from VF page. But i am getting the error as **blob variable do not exist**. Please check the below code.

```
     List<Account>  ObjectList1 = [SELECT id,Name FROM Account];
     Messaging.EmailFileAttachment csvAttc = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
     blob csvBlob = Blob.valueOf(ObjectList1);
     string csvname= 'Duplicate.xls';
     csvAttc.setFileName(csvname);
     csvAttc.setBody(csvBlob);
     Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email =new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
     String toAddresses = 'xyz@abc.com';
     String subject ='Duplicate Data';
     email.setSubject(subject);
     email.setToAddresses( toAddresses );
     email.setPlainTextBody('Duplicate Data');
     email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[]{csvAttc});
     Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of bits that won't work in your code:

```
Blob csvBlob = Blob.valueOf(ObjectList1);
```

`ObjectList1` is `List<Account>` in your code. `Blob.valueof` takes `String` as input. This is the source of your error.

Another error is in this line:

```
email.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
```

This method requires input of `List<String>`, and you are passing a single string.

But I think what you will have the most success by running a report through the Analytics API and generate the results as CSV (`String`) and then pass it into your `Blob.valueof()` method. This technique is discussed in [another StackExchange question that you can find here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/337/can-report-data-be-accessed-programatically/353#353).

Generating this through a report gives you the ability to change the data produced in the PDF without changing code. You can also secure access to the report, or open it up to other users to modify, if need be.

Comment: I accept the mistake in toAddresses part. Cant we do it without using reports as this thing comes in batch class.

Comment: You could just construct the CSV string in code, I suppose and return that. There are ways you can make an HTTP request to a VF page that renders PDF and then use the body that is returned. But I would always recommend the report option first. It may seem like more work now, but it is much more maintainable in the long run.

Comment: If its a string output how do I put into multiple rows in excel ??

Comment: Excel can be quite flexible with regards to formatted data in text. http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/file-formats-that-are-supported-in-excel-HP010014103.aspx#BMtextformats