# Download a report using python

Tags: api, reporting, python

I have a report that I want to download in a CSV format using a pyhton script. I searched the web for solutions, but none of them worked. [This one](http://brendansterne.com/2012/12/11/download-scrape-salesforce-reports-in-4-lines-of/) looked very promising and simple, but unfortunately does not work either. Any ideas would be helpful.

Update: Thats what I am trying to do when using the technique in the link I provided. I get some weird output and I am not sure what it means.

My code:

```
import requests

l = requests.get("https://login.salesforce.com/?un=MYUSERNAME&pw=MYPASS")
d = requests.get("https://na2.salesforce.com/00O40000003jBbP?export=1&enc=UTF-8&xf=csv",cookies=l.cookies)
print d.content
```

Output

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">





<script>
if (this.SfdcApp && this.SfdcApp.projectOneNavigator) { SfdcApp.projectOneNavigator.handleRedirect('https://login.salesforce.com/?ec=302&startURL=%2F00O40000003jBbP%3Fexport%3D1%26xf%3Dcsv%26enc%3DUTF-8'); }  else 
if (window.location.replace){ 
window.location.replace('https://login.salesforce.com/?ec=302&startURL=%2F00O40000003jBbP%3Fexport%3D1%26xf%3Dcsv%26enc%3DUTF-8');
} else {;
window.location.href ='https://login.salesforce.com/?ec=302&startURL=%2F00O40000003jBbP%3Fexport%3D1%26xf%3Dcsv%26enc%3DUTF-8';
} 
</script>

</head>


</html>



<!--
...................................................................................................
...................................................................................................
...................................................................................................
...................................................................................................
-->
```

Comment: Have you seen - [Can report data be accessed programatically](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/337/can-report-data-be-accessed-programatically)? It isn't specific to Python, but the basic premise is the same. Use the dedicated Analytics API or request based on the report Id with the `export=1` and `xf=csv` query string arguments.

Comment: @DanielBallinger I have seen it. In the link I provided the same approach is used I believe (to get a report use the report links). I have been looking at the different ways of downloading files in python using urllib, urllib2, httplib, and others, but did not come up with a solution yet.

Comment: As an alternative, you might consider Conga Courier appExchange which can send csv report to email recipients on a schedule

Comment: @Koba the technique definitely works. The question is, how do you apply it in Python? I don't know Python, but it should be a fairly common thing to make HTTP requests with cookies to a URL and read back the response stream.

Comment: Any error messages when you try to run the solution from the linked article?

Comment: @FrankZ Not and error msg, but I get weird output. I updated my question.

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure that a) the login was successful and b) your application is on the na2 instance?

Comment: @FrankZ It does? Hmm weird. Yeah I am sure about it. I will double check. How does your output looks like?

Comment: What's the output if you add these two lines after the first request? (and add an 'import json' of course)
print l.status_code
print json.dumps(dict(l.headers), indent=4)

Comment: @FrankZ here is the [output](http://pastebin.com/exRv4LdT)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16607/discussion-between-frankz-and-koba).

Comment: @Koba were you able to figure it out? I know this is an old thread but i'm having literally the exact same issue, even made an SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48443107/export-salesforce-report-as-csv

Answer (score 1):

I manged to do it with the below :

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
import requests
import base64
import json

sf = Salesforce(username=    #login
                ,password=  # password
                ,security_token= # token )

print "get sid ", sf.session_id

response = requests.get("https://instancename/reportid?view=d&snip&export=1&enc=UTF-8&xf=csv",
                  headers = sf.headers, cookies = {'sid' : sid})

response.contents
```

Comment: This doesn't work in 2023, tested today

Answer (score 0):

So this has been driving me crazy, but I figured it out.

you need to curl this:

```
curl https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/33.0 -H \"Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8\" -H \"SOAPAction: login\" -d @sf_login.txt
```

where sf_login.txt contains:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <env:Body>
    <n1:login xmlns:n1="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">
      <n1:username>username</n1:username>
      <n1:password>pass+token</n1:password>
    </n1:login>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>`

parse out the sessionId however you chose and store it as a variable in your python script.

After that post to SF like this:

```
r = session.post("https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token", params=payload)
```

Payload can be a list you set before hand containing the following:

```
payload = {'grant_type': 'password', 'client_id': 'xxxxxxxxx', 'client_secret': 'xxxxx', 'username': 'xxxx@xxxxx.com', 'password': 'pass+token'}
```

save the output and convert it to json
extract the access token and save it as a variable

once you have the sessionId and access token as variables construct a cookie+header list:

```
headers = {'Bearer': token}
cookie = {'sid': sid}
```

Then construct a final request:

```
d = requests.get("https://na2.salesforce.com/00O40000003jBbP?export=1&enc=UTF-8&xf=csv", headers=headers, cookies=cookie)
```

Printing content will yield you the csv

hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

This answer requires:

- pandas (because its perfect for this)
- requests
- csv

  ```
  def sfdc_to_pd(reportid):

      login_data = {'un': 'your_username', 'pw': 'your_password'}

      with requests.session() as s:
      s.get('https://your_instance.salesforce.com', params = login_data)
      d = requests.get("https://your_instance.salesforce.com/{}?export=1&enc=UTF-8&xf=csv".format(reportid), headers=s.headers, cookies=s.cookies)
      lines = d.content.splitlines()
      reader = csv.reader(lines)
      data = list(reader)
      data = data[:-7]
      df = pd.DataFrame(data)
      df.columns = df.iloc[0]
      df = df.drop(0)
      return df
      print df
  ```

I know you need this in csv format: to get that, you can just remove everything below `data = data[:-7]` and replace with code to write csv to disk.