# How to Run and Email a Report with a Custom Button?

Tags: apex, javascript, custom-button, button-overrides

Goal:

I would like to have users be able to click a button that will do the following upon click (aka, request):

1. Run Specific Reports
2. Attach Said Reports to a Specific Template
3. Email Said Template to a Specific Address
4. Refresh the Page
5. Display a Message to the User that their request has been submitted

I am familiar with how to achieve steps #3, #4, and #5, but I am at a loss of how to do steps #1 and #2.

Is this even possible with Salesforce? Do you have any ideas?

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Thanks!

Comment: or look at Conga Composer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/337/can-report-data-be-accessed-programatically) post that tells you how to run a report and get to the data programmatically. You would then have to format the data in say an html table as part of the email.

Or you could format the data as CSV and then create an email attachment... or however what ever format you want to the data in.

Comment: Thank you- I think this is going to work out quite well for me!

Comment: Good good! Glad I could help :)