# Is this Possible to retrieve a report names specific to object reference. Ex:Like for account object how many reports/dashboards are associated

Tags: reporting, dashboard, custom-report-type, report-chart

Requirement:-I want to fetch a report and Dashboard names which using Account ,contact,Opportunity,Lead And some custom object reference(Fields)).

Is this Possible to retrieve a report name specific to object reference.
Ex:Like for account object how many reports/dashboards are associated.

As this is business requirement early response is more appriciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know it can't be done with SOQL.

You probably could try with [Analytics API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_analytics/salesforce_analytics_rest_api.pdf) but it has some limitations.

The "old school" way would be to download all report types and report definitions to Eclipse IDE (or with any other tool of your choice). If you'd have > 5,000  reports the retrieval would have to be split into chunks - for example fetch few folders at a time.

Report definitions will be shown as XML files (sample is at the bottom of [Metadata API page for Report object](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_report.htm)).

You'll then be able to run text searches on the XML files (Ctrl+H in Eclipse but you could also use Windows "Find in files" or anything really). Search for your custom object's API name (`Xyz__` - ideally without the `c` at the end because you might see `Xyz__r` sometimes).

Personally I like Notepad++ "find in files" - easy to select the search results and paste to text file or Excel...

If that's too much work - go to the object's definition, clear the "allow reports" checkbox and soon your users will tell you which reports are related to that object ;)

Source : [Link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/337/can-report-data-be-accessed-programatically)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response,but I didn't get your second approach.I simply need report names with specific object.Could you please help me out in this

Comment: You need pull out Report object metadata, you will find the report and object name there.